# How to make a Tag cloud app that post on a website?

Tags: objective-c, twitter, tags

I want to make an app where the users can post messages that will be displayed on a website. The users would need to create a username and password to be able to post.

The app would be like a twitter, but only be able to post through the app and read the last few posts and not be able to write private messages.

The website would function like a huge cloud of thoughts where everyone could go and read what others have written. Once the post hit the cloud, they can't be deleted. Only me could delete posts.

All posts would have different color and font size, it would look like a huge tag cloud on the website.

How do I make an app and a website like this?

David H

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial application for [Google Application Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/) is an unstyled version of what you describe. They'll even host it for you for free (up to a non-trivial level of usage).

The tag cloud creation is not [so very hard](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/11/07/tag-clouds-gallery-examples-and-good-practices/) but without knowing your preferred language it is hard to point you to helpful libraries (there are plenty out there).

Getting people to use it will be the hard part.

**added in response to comment**:

Good luck on your endeavor. I would be surprised if you weren't able to learn everything you need to know and have a working web app by the time school starts. I found a simple [stand alone web cloud creation](http://www.geojeff.org/blog/00002/tag-cloud-image) library that explains what it does and will run on GAE. So now even that part is in place for you.

I'm tempted to make some pathetic reference to the sorts of computing that I did prior to high school, but I expect that you probably have SD **data** cards have more computational power than I had available to me. Kids these days! ;)

Comment: the app is for the iphone, I know a little html and php. I just want to learn this so I figure I start with the app since I have asked a lot of iphone dev questions before.

I start highschool in september and I want to learn as much as I can before that. I will be taking mainly dev classes. As for users, I am not that bothered of that I just have to get the people at school to try it.

David

Comment: I strongly suggest you then learn and use the Python API to GAE. Java has too much baggage that you learn for rapid development. (Java fans, that baggage has its use in the development of large applications (among others) but isn't warranted in the scenario the OP outlined).